# MSVCP100D.dll is missing on your computer debug mode Visual C++ 2012

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012

I know this question was asked before. But I need a real answer, **a real explanation**! 
When running (ctrl+F5) the code shown underneath,  in Visual Studio 2012 Express, in **Release mode**, everything works. When running it in **Debug mode**, I get:

**The program cant't start becaue MSVCP100.dll is missin from your computer...**

I already installed the Redistributable Package 2010 and 2012.

What is going on??? Please a detailed Explanation, that I can understand :) Thanks a lot!!!

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    Mat image = imread("Bild.jpg");

    namedWindow("Mein Bild");

    imshow("Mein Bild", image);

    waitKey(5000);

    //The member variable data is in fact a pointer to the allocated memory block that will contain
    //the image data. It is simply set to 0 when no image has been read.
    if(!image.data)
    {
        cout<<"No image has been createt"<<endl;
    }

    cout<<"height = " << image.size().height <<"\t width = "<< image.size().width<<endl;

    //page 27

    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the compiler options to change the runtime library worked for me (**"Configuration Properties"/"C/C++"/"Code Generation"**. In the item labelled **Runtime Library**, select **Multi Threaded (/MT)** for the release version and **Multi Threaded Debug (/MTd)** for the debug version). I did have to do both the debug and the release to get the release to work. Don't know why.

Note: I was using VC2010 Express version on Windows 7 to compile. I tested on an old XP machine. Another note: MS information at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: You have to change both, because the defaults are `/MD` and `/MDd`.

Answer (score 1):

By design. You are not allowed to redistribute Debug Mode executables. As the name says, they are for debugging, not releasing.

Comment: @newandlost: to the computer complaining about MSVCP100.dll. It's part of the Visual Studio install, and works in conjunction with the Visual Studio debugger. So, from the complaint it follows that you're running it on another computer.

Comment: I am NOT running it on an other computer. 

Like I've been writing above, I write that piece of code and press ctr+F5 in Visual Studio 2012 in the Debug mode, an I am getting this error.

Comment: Well, that's Visual Studio **2012**, but the DLL comes from VS **2010**. And that must be on another PC. (VS2012 uses MSVCP110D.dll)

Comment: I have never used VS2010. I have not been using an other computer.

Comment: @newandlost: That's rather strange. What then is causing the dependency on a Visual Studio 2010 Debug DLL?

Answer (score -2):

I got the same error and also tried all the solutions I could find on the internet for a couple of days but I finally managed to fix it myself.

If you're using Windows 7 try reinstalling your operating system. Since I was using Win 8, I just [refreshed my computer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/restore-refresh-reset-pc) and never received the error again. Once you get your code working don't forget to [create a restore point](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/create-a-restore-point) just in case :)

Note that if you refresh your computer, you'll have to install all your programs but all your personal files will still be there.