# exe generated with Visual Studio creates dll errors on other pc's

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2017

I wrote a programm with Visual Studio, that i wanted to share with some friends. But when taking the complete folder containing the debug folder containing my .exe file and sending it to friends it throws 3 errors:
missing vcruntime140.dll
missing MSVCP140D.dll
missing urctbased.dll
(the order is probably not correct)
We tried to reinstall/update Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable 2017 x64 on [this](https://support.microsoft.com/de-de/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads) page, but without any positive results.
Might this be a problem, that I'm using the SDL2 library? I copied the SDL2.lib into their Syswow64 folder and system32 folder, which removed that specific .dll error, but made the others first appear.

Comment: Choose the option to "statically link the C++ runtime libraries". Then there will be no dependence on redistributable components. Also, ship a *release* build to your friends.

Comment: @Bathsheba Statically linking might be a solution, but I'd rather not blow up the size of my programm, if there's another solution. Is it possible the error exists exclusivly due to not being a release build?

Comment: DLLS ending `....D.dll` are debug versions and should not (can not) be re-distributed.  As a side note putting DLLs into system directories should have been stop before Windows XP.  Put them into your application folder and/or run the redist installation package. What happens if another app tries to install/use a diffent version of SDL2 ?

Comment: Quite possibly - although you can statically link the debug runtime too.

Comment: In addition to Richard Critten's comment: build your project in Release configuration for using on another computers.

Comment: Hesitant to close this as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18952464/msvcp100d-dll-is-missing-on-your-computer-debug-mode-visual-c-2012/18953597#18953597. Opinions?

Comment: @MSalters I'm kind of unhappy with the given question, because it doesn't contain an answer and at least somewhat differs from from my problem, but do as you like.

Comment: @a_familiar_wolf: AT the very least, you should report the remaining errors for a release build. The "D" suffix shows you're trying to distribute a debug build, and that's a build you are expected to run inside Visual Studio - not on you friend's computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choosing Realese option before building project and then sending the whole Release folder to your friends should solve this problem.

Comment: Nope - that won't include VC++ DLL's

Comment: @MSalters You are right. It will only get rid of Debug-specific DLLs problems.

Comment: This works ... but _why_?  What is it about Debug executables that means they only work on the machine they're built on?